# CORS configuration not working in Spring Cloud Gateway

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-gateway, http-status-code-401

Accessing API from browser (a jQuery script) is getting blocked. Here is the error message I am getting:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8765/conversion/convert' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

My jQuery script in a HTML file:

```js
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'http://localhost:8765/conversion/convert',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer MY_JWT_TOKEN'
    },
    data: JSON.stringify({
        id: 1,
        from: 'usd',
        to: 'bdt',
        quantity: 100
    }),
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function(error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
});
```

Maven Dependencies and Versions:

1. spring-cloud-gateway: 2022.0.4
2. spring-cloud-starter-gateway: 3.1.6
3. spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server: 3.1.6
4. spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client

I have configured OAuth2 (Keycloak) with my API gateway and used CORS (globalcors) config in my Gateway service config file (yml) as directed on [official Spring Cloud page](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-gateway/reference/spring-cloud-gateway/cors-configuration.html). I also tried all the different approaches from internet, nothing seems working.

```yaml
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      resourceserver:
        jwt:
          issuer-ui: http://localhost:9000/realms/Microservices-demo-realm
          jws-algorithm: RS256
  cloud:
    gateway:
      globalcors:
        cors-configurations:
          '[/**]':
            allowedOrigins: "*"
            allowedMethods: "*"
            allowedHeaders: "*"
      default-filters:
        - DedupeResponseHeader=Access-Control-Allow-Credentials Access-Control-Allow-Origin RETAIN_UNIQUE
        - name: TokenRelay
      routes:
        - id: conversion-service
          uri: lb://currency-conversion
          predicates:
            - Path=/conversion/**
```

Here is the Google Chrome Network Console:

[image]

I have also tried from a tiny ReactJS app and CORS are being block from there as well. Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Please help!

Comment: CORS warnings are just a side-effect of the 401 response code. Your app needs to handle pre-flight `OPTIONS` requests outside of any authentication requirements

Comment: @Phil Thanks a lot for the hint. It worked for me. This is the working example:

`@Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain filterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
        http
                .authorizeExchange(autorize -> autorize
                        .pathMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**").permitAll()
                        .pathMatchers("/actuator/health/**").permitAll()
                        .anyExchange().authenticated())
                .oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2 -> oauth2.jwt(Customizer.withDefaults()));
        return http.build();
    }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way to avoid CORS errors without the need for CORS configuration is to have same origin (serve your website through the gateway too, not only the API).

```yaml
gateway-uri: http://localhost:7080
ui-uri: http://localhost:4200
rest-api-service-uri: http://localhost:6080


spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      default-filters:
      - DedupeResponseHeader=Access-Control-Allow-Credentials Access-Control-Allow-Origin
      routes:
      # Redirection from / to /ui/
      - id: home
        uri: ${gateway-uri}
        predicates:
        - Path=/
        filters:
        - RedirectTo=301,${gateway-uri}/ui/
      # Serve a SPA through the gateway (requires it to have a baseHref set as /ui)
      - id: ui
        uri: ${ui-uri}
        predicates:
        - Path=/ui/**
      # Access the API with BFF pattern
      - id: bff
        uri: ${rest-api-service-uri}
        predicates:
        - Path=/bff/v1/**
        filters:
        - TokenRelay=
        - SaveSession
        - StripPrefix=2
```

With

- this routes definitions
- gateway running on port 7080
- REST API running on 6080
- SPA hosted on let's say 4200

I can:

- access the SPA assets from `http://localhost:7080/ui/*` (request are routed to `http://localhost:4200/ui/*`)
- send REST requests to `http://localhost:7080/bff/v1/*` (request are routed to `http://localhost:6080/*`, the `/bff/v1` prefix being stripped)

So with this setup, from the browser perspective, all network exchanges are made with `http://localhost:7080` => no cross origin

#### P.S.

This is not the question, but configuring a gateway as a resource server is a bad idea, specially when it is queried by some Javascript code running in browsers.

It would better be configured as a client with `oauth2Login()` and the `TokenRelay=` filter. The REST APIs behind the gateway would then be candidates for `oauth2ResourceServer()` configuration. **I posted [a tutorial for that on Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cloud-gateway-bff-oauth2).**

Comment: I have set up where the gateway is set up as a resource server. I have some filters that will extract authentication details set some custom headers for the request and then pass them to the downstream services. I have my clients in angular and they act as OAuth clients. Do you think that this is a bad setup ?

Comment: Yes, I think that it is a bad setup. [Spring Security team thinks too](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/issues/297#issue-896744390). I wrote [this tutorial](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials/bff) to meet Spring Security team (and many other experts) recommendations.

Comment: @ch4mp Thanks for the feedback. I am not much hands on this area but will keep your comments in my mind. I am working on a POC, not sure how folks want to setup the system at my work.

Comment: @Naim I have posted a tutorial for configuring SPAs (Angular, React or Vue) on Baeldung: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cloud-gateway-bff-oauth2